# Closed Chrome with Incognito Mode Open

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, private-browsing

I had about 20 tabs open in Google Chrome, and about 5 in the incognito mode which is basically a personal version with its own set of daily use tabs, I know that when I close my incognito window I need to sign in back to all the tabs and recreate, but I now closed the main window.

I clicked on chrome  from the taskbar but that opens up the incognito mode, is there a way to open the main mode, which will automatically open from where I left off (because thats how its setup to open).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> will open a new window (normal, not incognito)

followed by:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> will open the last set of open tabs

As indicated in other answers you can right-click chrome icon on taskbas and select "New window"

The benifit of using shortcut method is that it will work the same way on Windows and Linux machines.

Comment: Or you can right-click on the icon on the "start menu" and choose "open new window", and the same for the taskbar.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jumplists for this. Left click on the Chrome icon in the taskbar, then without releasing the button drag up. At this point, for Chrome, you can either release the button over the third item up from the bottom, named after the shortcut (like "Chrome") in this case, or the 5th item up from the bottom, under subcategory tasks "New Window".

Note that the list item, if any, the left button is released over will be considered 'clicked' so apply caution not to release over "Close all windows" (unless that is your intention). To prevent this, the left button can be clicked over the icon on the taskbar, the pointer dragged up and away from the jumplist that will appear and then the button released, with the pointer NOT over the newly appeared jumplist. Then the required item can be clicked as normal.

[image]

EDIT: A simpler way of bringing up the jumplist is to right click the Chrome icon in the taskbar, as indicated in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Right-clicking the icon in the taskbar should allow you to open Chrome again in normal mode, rather than simply maximising your currently open incognito window.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider changing the shortcut on your taskbar for the "normal mode". If clicking it opens an incognito window, it's because it is set up to do so. Delete existing, create new from 'chrome.exe', and drag new to taskbar. You can also have both on taskbar...

Comment: No my chrome is not set to open incognito, it opens incognito only when its left open

Comment: I see.. I had misunderstood, and assumed that the click on taskbar was a fresh launch of chrome, not just bringing an open incognito window to forefront...thanks for clarifying.